# Restrict percolator call to a type in ElasticSearch

Tags: types, elasticsearch, restrict

As explained in the doc, when I store a query with _percolator, eg:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_percolator/test/kuku -d '{
  "color" : "blue",
  "query" : {
      "term" : {
        "field1" : "value1"
      }
   }
}'
```

This query will be run when I percolate a document on the 'test' index, but if I want to restrict it to the type 'foo' of the 'test' index the only solution is to add a type in the query :

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_percolator/test/kuku -d '{
   "type":"foo",
   "color" : "blue",
   "query" : {
       "term" : {
         "field1" : "value1"
       }
  }
}'
```

And when adding the document use

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/type1/_percolate -d '{
   "doc" : {
      "field1" : "value1"
    },
    "query" : {
      "term" : {
         "type" : "foo"
      }
    } 
  }'
```

Is there another solution ? 
I tried

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_percolator/test/foo/kuku
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative approach is to wrap your original query into a filtered query and add a terms filter for _type:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered":{
            "query": {
                "term":{
                    field1" : "value1"
                }
             },
             "filter": {
                 "term": {
                     "_type" : "type1"
                 }
              }
          }
     }
}
```